How to determine the n th number of Pi?
I use
N[Pi, 10^3]


3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781
6406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231
7253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109
7566593344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664
8213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364
3678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919
5309218611738193261179310511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793
8183011949129833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702
7705392171762931767523846748184676694051320005681271452635608277857713
4275778960917363717872146844090122495343014654958537105079227968925892
3542019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998
3729780499510597317328160963185950244594553469083026425223082533446850
3526193118817101000313783875288658753320838142061717766914730359825349
0428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927
876611195909216420199

How can I get numbers of Pi from 900 to 1000?

I am sure this was asked before. You could look at RealDigits which gives list of the digits, Then you can now take any sublist of these you want.

Try: ResourceFunction["NthDigit"][Pi, #] & /@ Range[900, 1000]

@DanielHuber Thank you very much.

@Nasser Thank you very much.

RealDigits[Pi, 10, 101, -899]
(*
  {{0, 3, 5, 9, 8, 2, 5, 3, 4, 9, 0, 4, 2, 8, 7, 5, 5, 4, 6, 8, 7, 3, 1,
    1, 5, 9, 5, 6, 2, 8, 6, 3, 8, 8, 2, 3, 5, 3, 7, 8, 7, 5, 9, 3, 7, 5,
    1, 9, 5, 7, 7, 8, 1, 8, 5, 7, 7, 8, 0, 5, 3, 2, 1, 7, 1, 2, 2, 6, 8,
    0, 6, 6, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 9, 2, 7, 8, 7, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 9, 5, 9, 0, 9, 
    2, 1, 6, 4, 2, 0, 1, 9, 8}, 
   -898}
*)

There are 101 digits from the 900th place to the 1000th place. The 900th digit is in the 10^-899 place (since the initial 3 is in the 10^0 place).
You can take just the digit list, obviously:
First@RealDigits[Pi, 10, 101, -899]

